# How can I determine if a wifi dongle supports AP mode before purchase?

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot

I would like to use my laptop as a wifi hotspot, but the wifi hardware does not support AP mode, which is required. So, I need to purchase a dongle.

How can I determine whether or not a dongle supports AP mode before I purchase it?

Comment: Look at the specs?

Comment: Is "Soft AP Mode" good enough? I see that mentioned, but not sure if that is the correct spec to look for or if there is something like "hard ap mode" which is what I may really need.

Comment: If you have windows here is a link which describes how to make your laptop into a WiFi Hotspot regardless of hardware.  http://www.howtogeek.com/214080/how-to-turn-your-windows-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04